# angular flex layout adjustment

Tags: angular, flexbox

How do we adjust the length of 2 fields using flex layout ? . Right now as you can see on the first screenshot the 2 fields are far from each other , I want to be the same on the second screenshot , what is the technique to do that using flex layout >? Thanks.

[image]

#html code

```
 <div fxLayoutAlign="space-between center" >
            <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                <mat-label>Start Date</mat-label>
                <input 
                  matInput
                  [(ngModel)]="dealPMRFormFields.dealName"
                  [required]="isExistingDeal">
              </mat-form-field>
              <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                <mat-label>End Date</mat-label>
                <input 
                  matInput
                  [(ngModel)]="dealPMRFormFields.dealName"
                  [required]="isExistingDeal">
              </mat-form-field>
          </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like the following

```html
<div fxLayoutAlign="space-between center">
  <div class="item" fxFlex="50">Hello</div>
  <div class="item" fxFlex="50">World</div>
</div>
```

Using the `fxFlex` directive you can assign certain parts of the space to selected elements.